# Seaborn load_dataset with dataframe

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I'm quite new to python and this is the first time that I am trying to create a graph with seaborn. I have worked through the seaborn tutorial but cannot find any explanation of how sns.load_dataset works. I am trying to load a dataframe which I have imported as a csv file.
e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
file = "/path/to/file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Then I imported the relevant libraries including numpy, pandas, matplotlib, pyplot and seaborn. Followed by:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
plot = sns.load_dataset("df")
```

At this point I get an error, which seems to suggest that it is looking online via a url for the dataframe. I've seen another post that suggests you need to upload data, however I'm sure this cannot be the case and we'd forever be uploading data to play around with charts/graphs. Does anyone know how I can point sns.load_dataset to a local dataframe or csv file?

Comment: if `df` is your dataframe, you should pass it to `load_dataset()` without the quotes.  by passing `"df"` you're passing a string, not the actual dataframe.

Comment: Could you post the complete error message?

Comment: I had the same question, and it I found the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30337377/6067848