# Why do i get HTTP400 error when i am plotting graphs in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am working on a dataset to visualize basic plots in python. I use `seaborn and matplotlib`. Up until yesterday, the packages worked perfectly fine until this error showed up:

```
stars = sns.load_dataset(vcsfeatures)
sns.boxplot(stars)
plt.xlim(-100, 8000, 500)
plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 424, in load_dataset
    urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I searched on this platform and all answers came from-out the intention to utilize a url or to get access to a web api.

This error occurs when i use simple plot code:

```
pd.DataFrame.boxplot(vcsfeatures)
pd.DataFrame.boxplot(userfeatures)
plt.ylim(-100, 1800)
plt.show()
```

also with fake data as `data = [1, 2, 3]`
I get this error whenever i try to call for a plotting library.

This used to work yesterday. **Also with seaborn, pandas and numpy the error comes up.**

What am I missing here in finding the solution?

If there is a question like this already, please redirect me as I am not able to find it.

Comment: Can you post the **complete** error traceback?!

Comment: I posted it :) @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30336324/3901060

Comment: @FamousJameous thank you, I am convinced that it not related to seaborn as the plots were working for both matplotlib and seaborn, even plotly. Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: And I am convinced that the error you show is related to seaborn, because the first line of the error traceback says so. If you want to ask about a different error, you would need to post the [mcve] that produces this other error and show this other error's traceback.

Comment: I know, I accepted his answer already :) i tried it out. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sns.load_dataset` requires a string as argument which evaluates to one of the available datasets at [`https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data).

E.g. `sns.load_dataset("tips")` would load the *tips.csv* file.

Also see [Seaborn load_dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336324/seaborn-load-dataset)

Supplying some other data or a string which does not have its corresponding file will of course not work.

Comment: My question is not bounded to the seaborn package. it happens also with matplotlib. even if i use matplotlib without seaborn. :(

Comment: I can only answer on what you provide in the question. If it's not seaborn related, why do you post a seaborn code?

Comment: I think that i show you also solely a `.plt` in my question to show that it is not only seaborn.

Comment: It 100% certain that the error you show is related to seaborn, because the error traceback says so. If you have a problem without seaborn, post the code and the error traceback you get with **that other code**.

Comment: ahh! your 100% is better than mine. it worked! Thank youu, i am very happy.