# Using local data in Python Seaborn returns file does not exist

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to utilize Seaborn to create a visualization.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
import os.path
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
tel = pd.read_csv('nyc.csv')
nyctel = sns.load_dataset(tel)
sns.stripplot(x="installation_id", y="mounting", hue="mounting", data=nyctel)
```

The official documentation for load_dataset is completely useless, so I found that someone had already asked a question about how it works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337377/6110631

I followed the format listed in the answer and imported pandas so I could use a local file (saved in the same folder). When I run the program however, I get

```
IOError: File nyc.csv does not exist
```

If I use an absolute path I get

```
IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)
```

It seems the problem is with this line:

```
nyctel = sns.load_dataset(tel)
```

because if I omit this line and the line beneath it and add `print tel` beneath the pd.read_csv line then the program works and it prints out the contents of the file. Somehow `load_dataset` is not letting me use that file though!

I am using the exact same code as in the answer linked above. Why would this not work for this local file?

Comment: Do you file in same location as code? May be you can try adding absolute path on `pd.read_csv`

Comment: ok, did you look at the link, from the link you posted above **load_dataset looks for online csv files on https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data.** if you go the link `nyc.csv` is not there.

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE Yes, but using pandas you can use local files

Comment: ok, may be I am confused then why do you need nyctel again, why not use tel? May be I will stop commenting after this. If you comment line `nyctel = sns.load_dataset(tel)` and only use `tel` in data, wouldn't it work?

Comment: You can always try slicing with small results something like `tel = pd.read_csv('nyc.csv')[:100]` for only 100 rows.

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE This runs instantly and without error but does not return any visualization. I guess this means my last line does not work: sns.stripplot(x=tel.installation_id, y=tel.number_of_phones, hue=tel.mounting, data=tel)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171734/discussion-between-0p3n5ource-and-interlinked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this via mobile so it's not tested:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import os.path

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
filename = 'nyc.csv'
file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
tel = pd.read_csv(file_path)

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
nyctel = sns.load_dataset(tel)

sns.stripplot(x="installation_id", y="mounting", hue="mounting", data=nyctel)
```

Comment: This gets me: IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)

Answer (score 1):

The `load_dataset()` is only necessary to create a Pandas DataFrames, out of an example database. In your case, you created a DataFrame whith `pd.read_csv('nyc.csv')`, so `sns.load_dataset(tel)` is unnecessary and not working.

Here is a quote from https://seaborn.pydata.org/introduction.html

> Most code in the docs will use the load_dataset() function to get
> quick access to an example dataset. There’s nothing special about
> these datasets: they are just pandas dataframes, and we could have
> loaded them with pandas.read_csv() or built them by hand. Most of the
> examples in the documentation will specify data using pandas
> dataframes, but seaborn is very flexible about the data structures
> that it accepts.