# Error 404 - coding with library given by the python website

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using the code given by the python graph website:
https://python-graph-gallery.com/110-basic-correlation-matrix-with-seaborn/
A simple code, I was testing the pairplot function. Just did the copy-paste.

The code I used is:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/raw/master/iris.csv')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Basic correlogram
sns.pairplot(df)
sns.plt.show()
```

And the error is:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-959108b5285e> in <module>()
      1 import seaborn as sns
----> 2 df = sns.load_dataset('https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/raw/master/iris.csv')
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
      5 # Basic correlogram

7 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [tutorial](https://python-graph-gallery.com/110-basic-correlation-matrix-with-seaborn/) you have mentioned, the code snippet is as follows:

```
# library & dataset
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Basic correlogram
sns.pairplot(df)
sns.plt.show()
```

For the `load_dataset()` function you just need to specify the dataset name.

Quoting directly from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30336324/10155936):

> load_dataset looks for online csv files on https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data.

You don't have to specify url, instead just the dataset name available from [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data)