# I am attempting to load a dataset using the seaborn function "load_dataset"

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, seaborn

I am attempting to load a dataset using the seaborn function "load_dataset" but i keep encountering `IndexError:single` positional indexer is out-of-bounds

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sms
from scipy import stats

df = sms.load_dataset('gapminder-FiveYearData.csv')

print df
```

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: It looks like your CSV element count in lines is not constant. Check that there are no random unescaped comma in the file

Comment: I would love to, but the data is much. take a look at the data here   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv

Comment: It appears that the issue is with how seaborn's load dataset function works. It does not accept local files as shown in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336324/seaborn-load-dataset