# Can't access seaborn example datasets

Tags: python, dataset, seaborn

I was trying to use 'tips' dataset from seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

### and I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 a = sns.load_dataset("anagrams")
      2 a.info()

File C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py:587, in load_dataset(name, cache, data_home, **kws)
    585 if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
    586     if name not in get_dataset_names():
--> 587         raise ValueError(f"'{name}' is not one of the example datasets.")
    588     urlretrieve(url, cache_path)
    589 full_path = cache_path

ValueError: 'anagrams' is not one of the example datasets.
```

Then I tried:

`sns.get_dataset_names()`

the output was an empty list: []

I can use seaborn plots. I also tried to update my seaborn using:

`!pip install seaborn --upgrade`

but it didn't help.

Could you please help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336324/seaborn-load-dataset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn load\_dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336324/seaborn-load-dataset)

Comment: What is your seaborn version and the output of `sns.utils.DATASET_NAMES_URL`?

Comment: this is my seaborn version : '0.13.1'
the URL checking command would be very useful. unfortunately, I saw it after the problem was solved, and obviously now it's returning the expected answer.

Answer (score 5):

It could be that you installed [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) a long time ago, loaded datasets then, which created a cache, and now are trying to use a new dataset.

Try to use `cache=False`:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips", cache=False)
```

The `load_dataset` function is explicitly not trying to download the dataset if you have a cache and the dataset name is not found:

```
if cache:
        cache_path = os.path.join(get_data_home(data_home), os.path.basename(url))
        if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
            if name not in get_dataset_names():
                raise ValueError(f"'{name}' is not one of the example datasets.")
            urlretrieve(url, cache_path)
        full_path = cache_path
    else:
        full_path = url
```

You can also try to delete the cache directory. Get its path using:

```
print(sns.utils.get_data_home())
```

Comment: cache=False

Excellent workaround. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on `python 3.10.0` and  `seaborn 0.13.1`.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

total_bill  tip sex smoker  day time    size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
```

Can you tell us your `python` and `seaborn` version?

you can also check what datasets are available with

```
sns.get_dataset_names()
```

Comment: "*Then I tried: `sns.get_dataset_names()` the output was an empty list: []*"

Comment: can you try to uninstall seaborn and install again?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the recommendation's and helps. The problem miraculously got solved. I decided to manually download the dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import urllib

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = pd.read_csv(response)
```

after doing that everything started working.

```
sns.get_dataset_names()
```

returned:

```py
['anagrams',
 'anscombe',
 'attention',
 'brain_networks',
 'car_crashes',
 'diamonds',
 'dots',
 'dowjones',
 'exercise',
 'flights',
 'fmri',
 'geyser',
 'glue',
 'healthexp',
 'iris',
 'mpg',
 'penguins',
 'planets',
 'seaice',
 'taxis',
 'tips',
 'titanic']
```

I don't understand why, but it worked.

Comment: FYI, you don't need `request`, you can directly use `pd.read_csv(url)` ;)